# how to hide if empty when the content type field number of values is unlimited

Tags: php, open-source, drupal-6, drupal-views

i am having problems hiding the label of the field in views if the field is empty when it accepts unlimited number of values.
any idea how to resolve this?
i tried this

```
 function alter_form_preprocess_views_view_fields(&$vars) {
   // Remove labels if value is empty.
   foreach ($vars['fields'] as $id => $field) {
     if (!$field->content) {
       unset($vars['fields'][$id]);
     }
   }
 }
```

it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did was create a new field as markup for every field that i would like to hide its label if it doesn’t have any value and created a tpl file for every one of those markup fields and did this:

```
<?php
    if(!empty($row->{node_data_field_d_a_name_field_d_a_name_value}[0]['value'])){
        print $output;
    }
?>
```

technically it is not a label but works just like it and it solved my problem.

notes: i removed the label from every field the markup and the field that had the value so that i wouldn't have multiple labels for the same field.